# Internationally recognized synonym/term for 'technical passport'?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What's the common, internationally recognized term for such a document:

> A technical passport is a document intended for the customer. It contains the most important technical data of the machine or device and the operating characteristics. The technical passport must be available throughout the life cycle of a device or machine. The technical passport is issued by the manufacturer according to the standards GOST 2.601-2013 and 2.610-2006. In certain cases, the technical passport must be presented when to a notified body. The technical passport shall be issues separately for each plant or machine and each serial number. The technical passport is written in Russian.
>
> ref: https://schmidt-export.com/technical-documentation/technical-passport

**The domain**

We're developing electrical machines audit system, each machine has its own tech passport. We can stick to just 'technical passport', yet it's an interesting thing to know about.

Comment: To me that sounds like *maintenance records*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard "***spec sheet***" used in this sense. Apparently it is also called a data sheet (or datasheet).

Wikipedia:

> A datasheet, data sheet, or **[spec sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datasheet)** is a document that
>   summarizes the performance and other technical characteristics of a
>   product, machine, component (e.g., an electronic component), material,
>   a subsystem (e.g., a power supply) or software in sufficient detail
>   that allows design engineer to understand the role of the component in
>   the overall system.
>   ...
>   It can be published by the manufacturer to
>   help people choose products or to help use the products.

Comment: Spec sheets are **not** issued to individual pieces of equipment.